# Streaming video from database in java

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming

I want to stream video from mysql database to some javascript based player example: jplayer, mediaelementjs

Right now I am using mediaelementjs to play video from direct links

```
wwww.somewebsite.com/videos/video1.mp4
```

But I want to play it from database. One option I have thought of is to read the video from database and keep it on server and then send the direct link of that video to the browser. This idea is really not scaleable if video size is large and number of users accessing videos.

Can someone share some thoughts to stream video from database?

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: I'm not sure streaming from a database is a good idea in general since that would involve some nasty locking and transaction issues for longer videos. Why don't you store the video files in the file system (you seem to do that already) and just store the (relative) path to the file in the db?